# Persistence bundle became Active only after “Aries JPA Container” bundle refreshment

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi

Problem is: All my **persistence bundles fails after Active[GracePeriod]**  with messages like:

```
  | ERROR | rint Extender: 2 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | ntainer.BlueprintContainerImpl$1  332 | 8 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.1.0 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.*** due to unresolved dependencies [(&(&(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=true)(osgi.unit.name=sessionunit))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:328)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)[:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_11]
```

And everything **works fine if we refresh “Aries JPA Container” bundle** while persistence bundles are in GracePeriod

**Question is: How could we avoid this ridicules refreshing?**

Thank you.

```
My detailed configuration: 
Apache Karaf (2.3.1) 
==== Hibernate Bundles 
[ 186] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] jackson-datatype-hibernate4 (0)
[ 217] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-commons-annotations (4.0.4.Final)
[ 218] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-core (4.2.7.Final)
[ 219] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-entitymanager (4.2.7.Final)
[ 220] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-envers (4.2.7.Final)
[ 221] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-osgi (4.2.7.Final)

==== Aries Bundles 
[   8] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint Core (1.1.0)
[   9] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint CM (1.0.1)
[  11] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.0.1)
[  12] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Util (1.1.0)
[  13] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy API (1.0.0)
[  14] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint API (1.0.0)
[  24] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX API (1.1.0)
[  28] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Core (1.1.1)
[  36] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint Core (1.1.0)
[  39] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint API (1.1.0)
[ 160] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container API (1.0.0)
[ 161] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container blueprint integration for Aries blueprint (1.0.1)
[ 162] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container (1.0.0)
[ 163] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container Managed Contexts (1.0.1)
[ 164] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI API (1.0.0)
[ 165] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI Core (1.0.0)
[ 166] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI RMI Handler (1.0.0)
[ 167] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI URL Handler (1.0.0)
[ 168] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI Support for Legacy Runtimes (1.0.0)
[ 201] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (1.0.0)
[ 202] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Karaf 2.3.3 because the older version contained a blueprint version that did have this rather strange effect. With the latest Version of Karaf (combined with a newer version of Blueprint) this isn't an issue anymore.

Comment: I have the same error, but we cannot upgrade Karaf as it is provided with Fuse. Do you know how it can be fixed with older Karaf (2.3.0.redhat-60024)?

Comment: There is a switch for using blueprint in a synchronous way.
Set org.apache.aries.blueprint.synchronous=true in the config.properties. That should help

Comment: This switch is actually turned on. We run everything on Fuse, maybe it is not active with Fuse? org.apache.aries.blueprint.synchronous = true. Our workaround it to add refresh JPA blueprint aries as a last command, but I don't like it

Comment: yep, doesn't sound nice, but since I have no clue about how the Fuse Karaf differs here I'm out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: ok, thank you, we spent hard time on this. The only difference we notice in the log between working version and not is: "No quiesce support is available, so managed persistence units will not participate in quiesce operations"

Comment: don't know, but doesn't the Fuse Karaf have a paid support for those issues? It's product isn't it?